# Hierarchical Bayes with bayesm: two second-levels

Tags: hierarchical-data, bayesian, mcmc, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

Currently I am implementing a *Hierarchical Bayes* model with panel data for I stores with T weeks, and where my dependent variable is sales of a brand. I aim to relate store-characteristics to the explanatory variables I am using, but I wish to have two separate second-levels. My model looks like this:

> y = intercept + alpha * X + beta * W + error term,

where I would like to introduce the second levels:

> alpha = lambda1 * Z + error
>
> beta = lambda2 * Z + error,

where Z contains the store-characteristics. However, as far as I know, I can only use one second-level when using `rhierLinearModel` in `bayesm`.

Does anybody know how I can specify the model or adjust the code to obtain two second-levels?

Thank you very much in advance!